# Migrating Watch OS companion app to new apple developer account - watchos companion app not getting installed from Appstore

Tags: ios, migration, watchos, adp

We have old apple developer program with some iOS apps which also have companion watch OS apps, let's name it ADP A. Now we've tried to migrate one of the apps to the new ADP, let's call it ADP B - everything went fine with iOS app, but watch OS companion app keeped living on the old A developer account.

Then I've tried to delete app identifier from ADP A (as bundle ID implicitly has Team ID prefix), let's name it "com.fruitapp.orange.watchkitapp", as it didn't allow me to create same app id in ADP B. After submitting new version of TestFlight build everything went fine - both iOS app and companion WatchOS app were installed on device successfully, communicating with each other.

However after deploying to the Apple store from ADP B and installing iOS app from AppStore, WatchOS app is not being automatically installed on watch device. Even after tapping "Install" from Watch app on iPhone, installation doesn't start - button does nothing.

I've also tried to change bundle id to "com.fruitapp.orange.watchkitapp", but at the time of submission it fails with error saying "changing bundle it <...> is not allowed for app <...>".

Did anyone meet the same problem and know how to solve it?